# How to get exact tap position of GestureDetector

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-layout

GestureDetector always returning same location for any image tapped.

```
while (i<numImages) {
    GestureDetector(
    onTap:(){
      _onImageTapped(i);
    },

   child: FadeInImage(
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      image: AssetImage(urls[i%5]),
       placeholder: AssetImage(urls[i%5]),
  
  )));
images.add(carImage);
i++;
 }
}
```

On card tapped function is as:

```
_onImageTapped(int position) {
        print('$position tapped');
   }
```

Comment: That code would not compile or do anything the way you posted it. Please post a [mcve], post what you do, what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the onTapUp, or onTapDown properties of the GestureDetector, that way you get a TapDownDetails or TapUpDetails etc. which have position details, use as below:

```
GestureDetector g = new GestureDetector(
    onTapDown: (details) 
    {
      print(details.globalPosition);
      print(details.localPosition);
    },
  );
```

See: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/TapUpDetails-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
 int index=i;
```

And

```
   _onImageTapped(index);
```

I got the index of image in which the user tapped.